# Python Selenium: Accessing Split Container Pane

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver, splitcontainer

I'm attempting to access a section of an internal webpage and the structure is setup with:

```
<div dojotype="i3:I3SplitContainer" ...> 
     <div dojotype="i3:I3SplitContainer" id="leftPane" ...>
     <div dojotype="i3:I3SplitContainer" id="rightPane" ...>
```

**Problem**:

Everything in the '...' were the same for the left and right panes. When the page is loaded I'm able to access everything in leftPane and only that. When I try to locate any elements in the rightPane, it's unable to find it.

I've never worked with Split Containers before and wondering if there's a way to switch focus on the panes using Selenium?

I've tried to treat them as switching frames but no luck sadly. Wondering if there's any way to navigate/access the split containers. Thank you!

Comment: Need more reproducible info. Please share full page html. you can do it by using `print(driver.page_source)` . Please [edit] you question and update with html.

Comment: I will grab as much as I can but I won't be able to get the full html unfortunately. The page is on an internal work server. If that halts trying to find a solution I understand and I'll keep working to find a workaround.

Comment: While I'm still working to see if I'm allowed to share the page source, the 'rightPane' has the 'style=hidden' even though it's still visible to the user. I hope that's not a hard stop because of it.